# install progressive web apps from a menu link

Tags: javascript, installation, hyperlink, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to install a pwa from a link?
For example:
you go to a domain name index.html page and view multiple links to different pwa apps.

Then click a link and it installs a pwa to that specific app (with or without) going to a landing page for that app?

As it is now:

if i go to
[www.domainname.com/subfolder/index.html](http://www.domainname.com/subfolder/index.html)

and I have set it up as a installable pwa, it installs and the icon appears on the devices home screen with a link to [www.domainname.com/subfolder/index.html.](http://www.domainname.com/subfolder/index.html.).

What im looking for is:

if i go to [www.domainname.com/index.html](http://www.domainname.com/index.html) i will see a menu of available apps. if i click an app link it will install the home screen icon and when that is pressed will go to [www.domainname.com/subfolder/index,html](http://www.domainname.com/subfolder/index,html) as the start page, without first going to the app main screen.

I have been experimenting with this, but i cant get it to work, just checking if it is possible, or my code is wrong.

Comment: No, you can not, because installing a PWA relies on the manifest.json file

Comment: Thanks jaromanda for the reply.. I just found this article:  [link](https://web.dev/add-manifest/)  and this line: start_url #

The start_url is required and tells the browser where your application should start when it is launched, and prevents the app from starting on whatever page the user was on when they added your app to their home screen. Im going try this method: i'll send the user to the install page with a splash screen of the app and the .json.file.. then see if the start-url will take me to the correct page when launched. Ill let you know if this works. Rgs Antony

Comment: The user must be ON the HTTPS site you want installed, and they must say yes to the pop-up. AND your website must pass all the criteria for a valid PWA. You can use the Chrome Lighthouse tool to help you with that.

Comment: `Ill let you know if this works` - it wont

Comment: hi Jaromanda.. sorry for the long delay to reply...  What i managed to do, thanks to your first advice (the .json file must be present) is use a good old fashioned iframe to load the app install screen. Ive only tested it on android 9.0 so far but all is working well.. I still have a few tweaks to make before i give the code here.. The position of the install button seems irregular, and also how to close the iframe when completed. i have experience here just trying to find the best method.. You got me thinking: how to load the .json file while on the same page and that's how i got this idea..

Comment: Here's what i got: As per your comment the iframe idea works perfectly on a mobile device, why?? because the user can go to home-screen and click the icon to use the application which loads the start_url of the app. This all works fine.. On Pc its a different story, the cache and db all install perfectly, but then there was no way to go to the actual start page, here's where i got stuck.. Here's what i came up with:

Comment: on the install page if !mobile device, i set interval function which checks for a specific image in a folder. In my sw.js file i added this image last in the cache lists and under my temp cache array. This is the array that goes network first then cache. once the image is detected, i added an message to the main page to show activity and three seconds later change the install url to the start_url in the browser.

Comment: This seems messy and hacky, but it is working perfectly... What i haven't been able to do is find is a way to redirect to the start page from within the install process after service worker completes. So how do i update now!! in my main js file i have a background sync function. When my main app opens it looks to a indexxeddb variable, if update is eminent, it auto loads the new UI install page and the process repeats, on PC and mobile devices. And voilet!! its working

Comment: You have to remember! i was on a standard web html page, i loaded the install page in a Iframe which i wrapped in a Div popup, the interval function is on the main html page, the iframe popup loads the cache of the application. When the process is totally complete, the main page closes the iframe popup and heads to the start_url in the browser. I'm still toggling between this and the iframe. but you can do what you feel is right for you.

Comment: One more thing: i forced the application to full screen non mobile only and did a onchange event. If the screen is not full the application page will change to something else, if full screen is re-enabled will switch back ti application. In fullscreen mode i keep focus on the dom and this gives me control over all keyboard and mouse click events. If strange activity is detected i force header to new page, so no developer or hacky activity on my application.. Its a pwa, which gives full license to go full screen mode which hit me a few days a go. I hope this can help someone!

Comment: @Jaromanda AAAAAAHHHHH i see now, The manifest doesn't load when in a iframe :(.. up to now Ive just been testing on a laptop with laptop browser and wamp server with http - i uploaded a sample to my host and tested with https no luck with the manifest.json file loading. HOWEVER!! the sw.js file loads fine, and for web applications on PC, do i need the manifest file? on a mobile device when user clicks install i can just jump out of the iframe and continue as such and after install inform the user to go to app icon. On a pc i can continue in the iframe,

Comment: and add the actual app link to the users web profile for direct access.. and as explained use the background sync or a web call to check for cache versions and updates and to redirect to the install if an upgrade is eminent.. then the process just loops again..

Answer (score 0):

i tried subdomian works, with https for earch subdomain is ok, let me try and post comment later for if subfolder is work